# Excel file updated but no change: Export query to excel without header

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, module, export-to-excel

My VBA code is supposed to transfer my **query** in MS Access (without header)[image]
to **cell K17** on an existing excel spreadsheet named **Totals**.

When I run the module, under the property of the excel file, last modified time did get updated to when I run the module. But I don't see my query on the excel spreadsheet.

Any advice on my code will be highly appreciated. Thank you so much!

```
Sub TransToXL()

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWS As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim acRng As Variant
    Dim xlRow As Integer

    Dim qry As QueryDef
    Dim rst As Recordset
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\August 2017.xlsx")
    Set xlWS = xlWB.Worksheets("Totals")

    xlRow = (xlWS.Columns("K").End(xlDown).Row)

    Set qry = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("DollarsSold")
    Set rst = qry.OpenRecordset

    Dim c As Integer
    c = 11
    xlRow = xlRow + 16

    Do Until rst.EOF
        For Each acRng In rst.Fields
            xlWS.Cells(xlRow, c).Formula = acRng
            c = c + 1
        Next acRng
        xlRow = xlRow + 1
        c = 1
        rst.MoveNext
        If xlRow > 25 Then GoTo rq_Exit
    Loop

rq_Exit:
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set xlWS = Nothing
    xlWB.Close acSaveYes
    Set xlWB = Nothing
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

The variable c is the one that stores colum number, in which c =1 means column A, 11 will be K. In this code, I'm confused about the way I set `xlRow+16`. `xlRow+16` , and c = 11 is not pointing out to K17. Any advise on this? Thank you!

Comment: Please be more specific and detailed: What do you want to acheive? What is NOT working? Error messages?

Comment: Apologies that my question was not that specific. I have just updated to double-check that 'xlWS.Cells' points to cell K17 @peakpeak

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You are the expert regarding your case and you know everything about it. Please do not assume that other people also have the full knowledge of it.
Please be more specific and detailed: What do you want to acheive? What is working already? What is not working like it should? What are the error messages?

Comment: @peakpeak 'xlWS.Cells' and 'xlRow+1' is not pointing out to cell K17. How can I fix this? I set c to store colum nnumbers. Thank you for being patient with me!

Comment: @peakpeak Nothing is working except that the excel file tells me the right last modified time. The query should be exported to the Excel, the exact cell that I pinpoint to. There is no error message regarding syntax of the code. Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you review your code, single-step it and use an abundance of breakpoints and prints in the Immediate Window. There's no shortcut here. If someone suggests a solution, you'd still be lost next time your code fails. You MUST learn to code and DEBUG. No shortcut unless you hire someone of course ....

Comment: @peakpeak gotcha thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you are using a Do Until loop? If the recordset only has 1 row of data (the total) it looks like you could remove the loop and just use something like:

```
xlWS.Range("K17").Value = rst.Fields(0)
```

This would appear after the "Set rst.." line.